# Get key values from array of dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, json, dictionary

I have an array of values for example a = [1,2,3] and array of dictionaries b =[{2:"a"},{3:"b"},{45:"r"},{16:"a"}]. How can I get values from b which keys match the values in the array. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In objective-c**

```
NSMutableArray *c = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSNumber *i in a) {
    BOOL iFound = NO;
    for (NSDictionary *dict in b) {
        if ((NSNumber *)[[dict allKeys] firstObject] == i) {
            iFound = YES;
            [c addObject:(NSString *)[[dict allValues] firstObject]];
        }
    }
    if (!iFound) {
        [c addObject: [NSNull null]];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@",c);//("<null>",a,b)
```

**In swift**

```
let a = [1,2,3]
let b = [[2:"a"],[3:"b"],[45:"r"],[16:"a"]]
let c = a.map { i in b.first(where: { $0.keys.first == i })?.values.first }
print(c)//[nil, Optional("a"), Optional("b")]
```